# Как прибавить к массиву из wchar_t символ(ы)?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Например:

```
wchar_t fldr[] = L"text1";
```

Как я могу прибавить к text1 ещё какие-либо символы?

Comment: `L"text1" L"text2"`

Comment: Места надо выделить побольше, чтоб было куда добавлять, а потом - [`wcscat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для соединения во время компиляции просто пишите подряд `L"text1" L"append"`. Для рантайм соединения используйте `std::wcscat` или `std::wcsncat`.

Эти функции описаны в хедере `<cwchar>`.

Дока - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cwchar.